# Content of Collection never updated warning

Tags: java, intellij-idea

All,

The following snippet:

```
List<SomeClass> mylist = myMap.getOrDefault("Name of key", new ArrayList<>());
```

causes my IntellijIdea to produce this 'Content of Collection never updated' warning - highlighting the 'new ArrayList<>()' part.

If I change this to:

```
List<SomeCLass> defaultList = new ArrayList<>();
List<SomeClass> mylist = myMap.getOrDefault("Name of key", defaultList);
```

this warning disappears.

Should I ignore this warning .. suppress it .. or is there something I can do to fix it?

Comment: Is the map guaranteed to contain `"Name of key"`? Do you ever update the content of `mylist`, or just read its contents?

Comment: `Should I ignore this warning` It depends on what you are going to do with `mylist` later. If you add some item to `mylist` in case `"Name of key"` doesn't exist in map then your map won't be updated. In this case you should manually associate `defaultList` with "Name of key" (or use `Map::compute` do it implicitly). If you just read from `mylist` then it's OK and nothing to worry about

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko "then it's OK and nothing to worry about" but you may as well use `Collections.emptyList()`, so you don't have to create a new thing.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, the only caveat is that `Collections.emptyList()` is immutable, so if you associate it with some key in map, you won't be able to add anything into it

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I guess, but associating the same list with two keys in the map is grim.

Comment: @AndyTurner - I don't understand your question .. no, the key isn't guaranteed to be in the map, that is why I want to return an empty list when it isn't. And yes, I update the content of myList later on after which I 'put' it back in the map with the key.

Comment: "no, the key isn't guaranteed to be in the map" if it was guaranteed to be in the map, that's one way in which you are certain not to use the new list. That's why I asked.

Comment: If you always put it into the map (with the same key), use `myMap.computeIfAbsent("Name of key", k -> new ArrayList<>())` instead of `getOrDefault`.

Comment: Nice one - that saves me putting it back at the end by the looks of it. Thanks.